# page-numbering doesn't work

Tags: page-numbering

here it is my document

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\input{frontmatter/frontespizio}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{mainmatter/chapter_1}
```

what it happens is that `tableofcontents` receives arabic numbering and I don't get roman numbering

Comment: Please always post _complete_ _small_ documents that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page number form is used that is active, when the page is output. Thus when `\pagenumbering{arabic}` is called, the page of the table of contents is not yet output.
Add something like `\newpage` to start a new page, e.g.:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

If you are using document class `book` or similar consider using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Since I'm using book class I resolved using \frontmatter and \mainmatter.

Comment: I resolved the problem putting \mainmatter before first chapter and pagenumbering{roman} before tableofcontents right?

Comment: @Mazzy Or `\frontmatter`. Internally it also uses `\cleardoublepage` with `\pagenumbering{roman}`.

Comment: I got this problem... I have the first six pages of my class book belonging to frontmatter section. I would they have no numbers. I would numbering using roman numbers beginning tables of contents.HOw can I do?

Comment: @Mazzy You could switch the page style `\pagestyle{empty}` for the first pages and using `\frontmatter` afterwards, or ...

Comment: unfor tunately it doesn't work. I set first pages \thispagestyle{empty} but the tableofcontents doesn't start from I(arabic number)

Comment: @Mazzy Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.